# Can't find source for specific jar/class when debugging tomcat in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, tomcat

I'm fairly new to java/eclipse development and I'm having a bit of a problem debugging code from a specific jar in a web app that my company uses.

First off, I have Tomcat setup properly and can run the webapp successfully (other than the bug that I'm trying to find!). There are about two dozen jar files in the lib directory for the webapp, and when I've tried to debug files in other jars the debugger catches their breakpoints correctly and everything is happy. Breakpoints I set in code in the new jar are skipped, and when I catch a breakpoint further along the debug stack any attempt to click to the class I'm interested in results in "Source not found".

I click the "Edit Source Lookup Path..." button, click the project that contains the code, and it simply returns me to the "Source not found" error. I've tried setting up the lookup path both as a project as well as a File System Directory and a Workspace Project. Same result every time.

I'm a little fuzzy on how exactly the debugger ties a particular function call in the debug stack window to source code - is it simply based on the package and class name of the course file? If so, I can't see why it wouldn't be working.

Any ideas?

Comment: Something I just noticed - each time I click "OK" after selecting the Source Lookup Path, code blinks in the window for a fraction of a second before the "Source not found" message shows up again. It's so fast I can't tell with 100% certainty that it's the file I'm looking for, but I'm fairly certain it is. Does that indicate anything? Is there an eclipse error log that might show something? Is this just an eclipse bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are pointing at the right directory. If the class was com.foo.SomeClass then you need to set the src directory to the base directory such that Eclipse can find $basedir/com/foo/SomeClass.java. This isn't necessarily the root of the project, it might be $project/src, or even $project/src/main/java for Maven projects.

Comment: When I add the Source Lookup Path as a Java Project that's currently in the workspace, shouldn't that guarantee that it's looking in the right place? That's how I've added the other jars that are debug-able.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was missing the fact that a project was renamed, moved to a different repo and had a nearly identical package name... operative word being "nearly". Thanks locka for the only response!

```
com.companyname.java.x.y.z.classname != com.companyname.java.y.z.classname
```

Answer (score 0):

I hava a suggestion To resolve your problem in another way  :
if U  want to debug something which donot inlude tomcat lib or other lib bind to Tomcat , like struts2 which  need to process request and response .

please run program in main function even you  use spring ;

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 

    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                    "classpath*:/applicationContext.*.xml"); // check your applicationCntext formate , maybe applicationContext-*.xml ;

    context.afterPropertiesSet();
    find(context);
}
private static void find(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context) {

    Map beans = getContext().getBeansOfType(SomeCLass.class);
 SomeCLass   bean=beans.values().iterator().next();
bean.callFunction();

}
```